# JavaScript onClick href

Tags: php, javascript

with the use of `<a>` tag, i can put like:

```
<a href="include/sendemail.php?id_user=<?= $_GET['id_user'];?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure want to send an email?');" >Send Email</a>
```

and how do apply that code to button :

```
<input type="button" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure want to send an email?');"  value="Send Email" >
```

Comment: What you have will work. What is it doing/not doing that you don't expect?

Comment: *(sidenote)* Event attributes are considered bad practise. [Try to make them unobtrusive instead.](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: @Michiel Pater yes thanks for everyone :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like achieve your goal with only a little change, try something like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="if(confirm('Are you sure want to send an email?')) { document.location.href = 'include/sendemail.php?id_user='; } " value="Send Email" />
```

Comment: No, you don't put `javascript:` at the beginning of `onXYZ` attributes. They contain *code*, not a URL. The fact it works at all is basically a coincidence (you're defining a *label*).

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="button" onclick="return myFunc();"  value="Send Email" >

<script>

function myFunc()
{
 var flag = confirm('Are you sure want to send an email?');
 if(flag)
  document.location.href = "include/sendemail.php?id_user=<?= $_GET['id_user'];?>" ;
 else
   return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Buttons are not hyperlinks.

To make a button navigate to a different page, you can write `location = 'URL';` in the `click` handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="include/sendemail.php" method="GET">
<input type="hidden" name="id_user" value="<?php echo intval($_GET['id_user']); ?>" />
<input type="button" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure want to send an email?');"  value="Send Email" />
</form>
```

You could also use `onsubmit` of the `<form>` tag.